# How is DHCP request message broadcasted?

Tags: ip, dhcp

The broadcast address of DHCP request message is 255.255.255.255. Will this request message go through routers? It seems to be yes as the destination address is 255.255.255.255. However, it does not sound logical, because if the DHCP request message spreads in the whole internet, any DHCP server in the internet will be able to allocate IP for me, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When your computer sends a packet of data to 255.255.255.255, it will actually map that to the MAC address `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`. The packet is then sent out of your computer to the switch (or whatever your computer is plugged in to) with a destination of `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`.

Switches know that packets destined for that MAC address should be sent out of all ports so the net effect is that the packet reaches every device connected to the same switch (or a switch further down the chain). It will also reach anyone connected to the same network via a bridge (including bridging wireless APs) as bridges forward all packets including broadcasts (The idea of a bridge is that it should be transparent - everything in one side goes out the other). Routers normally will not forward broadcast messages between separate networks.

This area, that covers all devices connected via switches/hubs or bridging is called a "broadcast domain" in networking speak for that exact reason - All devices inside a broadcast domain will receive broadcasts sent by any other device in that same area.

Answer (score 11):

No it wont traverse routers unless you setup a dhcp relay agent. Broadcast messages are only broadcasted on the broadcast domain of the host (subnet).

Answer (score 0):

DHCP request is a broadcast with respect to layer 2 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)and layer 3(255.255.255.255). This is the behavior with respect to Cisco Devices, when you enable DHCP in it.
However there is a difference when it comes to Windows servers. DHCP request and acknowledgement are unicasts there.

Answer (score -2):

255.255.255.255 is not just another IP Address; it's a broadcast address so routers know not to forward it.

Answer (score -4):

The first packet should be broadcast but after getting IP from a server it will send uni cast to that server when the lease will expire.